# Why do 2 time structs with the same date and time return false when compared with ==?

Tags: go, time, struct, date-comparison

I have a `time.Time` created using `time.Date()`. I then calculate the number of nanoseconds between `1970/1/1 00:00:00.000000000` and that time.

I then take the nanoseconds and turn them back into a `time.Time` using `time.Unix()`.

However, if I compare the reconstituted time with the original using `==`, it returns false. If I subtract these 2 times, the resulting duration is 0. If I compare these 2 times using `time.Equal()`, it returns true.

If I create another time using `time.Date()` with the same values as the first time, using `==` to compare this new time and the original time results in a true.

This is the code that demonstrates this ([Golang Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/YGj_oil0kc)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t1 := time.Date(2016, 4, 14, 1, 30, 30, 222000000, time.UTC)


    base := time.Date(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, t1.Location())
    nsFrom1970 :=t1.Sub(base).Nanoseconds() // Calculate the number of nanoseconds from 1970/1/1 to t1

    t2 := time.Unix(0, nsFrom1970)

    fmt.Println(t1)
    fmt.Println(t2)
    fmt.Println(t1.Sub(t2)) // 0
    fmt.Println(t1 == t2) //false
    fmt.Println(t1.Equal(t2)) //true

    t3 := time.Date(2100, 2, 1, 21, 21, 21, 222000000, time.UTC)
    fmt.Println(t1 == t3) //true
}
```

Why does the reconstituted time return false when compared with the original time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) is a `struct`. When you try to compare them with `==`, quoting from the [Spec: Comparison operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

> Struct values are comparable if all their fields are comparable. Two struct values are equal if their corresponding non-[blank](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) fields are equal.

So `t1 == t2` will compare all the fields of the 2 `Time` struct values. The `Time` struct contains not just the second and nanosecond since a base time, it also contains the location as a pointer: `*Location`, so `==` will also compare the location fields. Comparing pointers:

> Pointer values are comparable. Two pointer values are equal if they point to the same variable or if both have value `nil`. Pointers to distinct [zero-size](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees) variables may or may not be equal.

And this is why comparing the times with `==` gives a `false` result: 2 locations may denote the same location even if their address is different, and this is your case.

To prove this:

```
fmt.Println("Locations:", t1.Location(), t2.Location())
fmt.Printf("Location pointers: %p %p\n", t1.Location(), t2.Location())
fmt.Println("Locations equal:", t1.Location() == t2.Location())
```

Output:

```
Locations: UTC UTC
Location pointers: 0x1e2100 0x1e6de0
Locations equal: false
```

This is documented in `time.Time`:

> Note that the Go == operator compares not just the time instant but also the Location. Therefore, Time values should not be used as map or database keys without first guaranteeing that the identical Location has been set for all values, which can be achieved through use of the UTC or Local method.

If `t1` and `t2` would also contain the same `*Location` pointer, they would be equal even if compared with the `==` operator. This can be ensured by calling [`Time.UTC()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.UTC) or [`Time.Local()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Local) method on them which returns a `time.Time` value where the same location pointer (`*Location`) is used. Or by using the [`Time.In()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.In) method which will *set* the specified location pointer (after the proper conversion), e.g.:

```
t2 = t2.In(t1.Location())
fmt.Println("Locations:", t1.Location(), t2.Location())
fmt.Printf("Location pointers: %p %p\n", t1.Location(), t2.Location())
fmt.Println("Locations equal:", t1.Location() == t2.Location())
fmt.Println(t1 == t2)     // Now true
fmt.Println(t1.Equal(t2)) // Still true
```

Output:

```
Locations: UTC UTC
Location pointers: 0x1e2100 0x1e2100
Locations equal: true
true
true
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/WO8F4Qh8RH).