# Why these two time.Time instances are same for UTC and different for another location?

Tags: go

I'm expecting these two `time.Time` instances are the same. But, I'm not sure why I got the compare result is false.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := int64(1497029400000)

    locYangon, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Yangon")
    dt := fromEpoch(t).In(locYangon)

    locYangon2, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Yangon")
    dt2 := fromEpoch(t).In(locYangon2)

    fmt.Println(dt2 == dt)
}

func fromEpoch(jsDate int64) time.Time {
    return time.Unix(0, jsDate*int64(time.Millisecond))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/EOrW8lWz73)

If I change `"Asia/Yangon"` to `"UTC"`, they are the same.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := int64(1497029400000)

    locYangon, _ := time.LoadLocation("UTC")
    dt := fromEpoch(t).In(locYangon)

    locYangon2, _ := time.LoadLocation("UTC")
    dt2 := fromEpoch(t).In(locYangon2)

    fmt.Println(dt2 == dt)

}

func fromEpoch(jsDate int64) time.Time {
    return time.Unix(0, jsDate*int64(time.Millisecond))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Nn3MzmiXoH)

Note:  I'm aware of `Equal` method (in fact, I fixed with `Equal` method.) But after more testing, I found some interesting case which is "UTC" location vs "Asia/Yangon" location. I'm expecting either both equal or both not equal.

**Update**: Add another code snippet with "UTC".
**Update2**: Update title to be more precise (I hope it will help to avoid duplication)

Comment: From the time documentation: `Do not use == with Time values`. You must use the Equal method

Comment: The Location is stored as a pointer in the time struct, so you are comparing 2 different pointer values to Location structs which is why they're different. UTC just happens to be the default which uses a nil pointer value, and therefor are equal. This is an implementation detail, there's no reason to ever use the == with time values, and the behavior may change again with go1.9 which uses monotonic time.

Comment: @JimB thank you. Can u pls put it as answer so that I can accept?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [Why do 2 time structs with the same date and time return false when compared with ==?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614921/why-do-2-time-structs-with-the-same-date-and-time-return-false-when-compared-wit/36615458#36615458)

Answer (score 0):

`LoadLocation` seems to return a pointer to a new value every time.

Anyway, the *good* way to compare dates is `Equal`:

```
fmt.Println(dt2.Equal(dt))
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/9GW-LSF0wg.